# ASP - Prompt save file dialog from streamwriter

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently I have the text file going to desktop, in ASP how can I prompt a file save dialog for the user? The result is string from the streamreader as "result" as follows:

```
StreamWriter FileWriter = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "file.txt"));

                FileWriter.Write(result);

                FileWriter.Close();
```

Comment: ASP?  Nothing about what you are doing right there is going to save anything to the desktop of the user using a browser.  Can you please elaborate more on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Basically, where do I specify streamwriter to save the file and how do I prompt the user using a save as dialog to save the file? After a link or button is clicked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String FileName = filename;
String FilePath = filepath;
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "text/plain";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
response.TransmitFile(FilePath + FileName);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
StreamWriter FileWriter = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream);
FileWriter.Write(result);
```

I didn't try the code, but maybe you need to omit the call to `FileWriter.Close()` since it will try to dispose the stream. If not, then you should be using `using` instead. If it's too problematic, write to the stream directly with its `Write` method or use a `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 2):

An example from one of my apps that does it.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tempFileName = Request["tempFileName"];  // the temp file to stream
    string attachFileName = Request["attachFileName"];  // the default name for the attached file

    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(Path.GetTempPath() + tempFileName);
    if (!file.Exists)
    {
        pFileNotFound.Visible = true;
        lblFileName.Text = tempFileName;
    }
    else
    {
        // clear the current output content from the buffer
        Response.Clear();

        // add the header that specifies the default filename for the 
        // Download/SaveAs dialog 
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + attachFileName);

        // add the header that specifies the file size, so that the browser
        // can show the download progress
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());

        // specify that the response is a stream that cannot be read by the
        // client and must be downloaded
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        // send the file stream to the client
        Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
    }        
}
```

Comment: You might consider setting the `Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";` line to the actual mime type of the file, if known.

Answer (score 1):

```
string path = Server.MapPath(your application path);
WebClient client = new WebClient();            
byte[] data = client.DownloadData(new Uri(path));
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "aspnet.pdf"));
Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

try this code.. its helpful
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if its still open but just to help others

Just use this code it should work to prompt the user to open a dialog for opening or saving the file on the system ....

```
byte[] bytesPDF = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\sample.pdf");

        if (bytesPDF != null)
        {

            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= DownloadSample.pdf");
            Response.ContentType = "application/octectstream";
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytesPDF);
            Response.End();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you first had a 1-tier (desktop) app that was saving a file using C# to the user's file system.   You are now trying to transition to a 2-tier app with your C# code running on the server tier, and the user's browser representing the other tier.  There is nothing you can do in C# on the server to write a file to the browser user's file system directly.

That being said, what you need to do is write the file to the HTTP response stream with a content type of something like application/octet-stream.  Are you actually using ASP or ASP.NET?  If the latter, you should have access to the response stream through a variety of means, but start with the Response object (available from the page, but also available via HttpContext.Current.Response).